# Angular2 MdInputContainer focus after view init

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have a component that has some `md-input-container` elements. I would like to set focus on the first one when the view loads.

The way I am implementing this is by creating a `@ViewChild` property and then calling focus on it `ngAfterViewInit`. There are no errors but, the focus is still not working.

```
export class AdminUserComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(MdInputContainer)
    private firstInput: MdInputContainer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.firstInput._mdInputChild.focus();
    }
}
```

I tried setting the focus code in a setTimeout function but that didn't make a difference. 
Has anyone successfully set focus on a material input when the view loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I should have been using `MdInputDirective` instead of `MdInputContainer`

```
export class AdminUserComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(MdInputDirective)
    private firstInput: MdInputDirective;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.firstInput.focus();
    }
}
```